# How to include a pipe executing a command with FileUtils#sh?

Tags: ruby, shell, pipe

I know about enough Ruby to be dangerous, so I'm writing a bunch of build automation scripts as Rake tasks mostly by working from examples in the API documentation.

I'm scripting a bunch of build commands with code like this:

```
results = {}
schemes.each { |scheme|
    command = "xcodebuild", "-scheme", scheme
    if options.configuration
        command.push "-configuration", options.configuration
    end
    command.push "archive"

    sh *command do |ok, res|
        results[scheme] = ok
    end
}
```

This works fine, but dumps a *lot* of output to the console that kind of gets in the way. So I'd love to pipe this stuff through [xcpretty](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty) to reformat it.

If I actually run the command from my terminal, it works fine:

```
xcodebuild -scheme Foo -configuration Release archive | xcpretty
```

But if I modify the Rake task to just append those parts to the end of the command array, `sh` thinks they're arguments to `xcodebuild`.

```
    command.push "archive", "|", "xcpretty"
```

I've seen a number of examples using `sh` with pipes in its string form, but not the array form. Because of the nature of the commands I'm building—optional arguments, arguments with spaces and other characters—the array form is much cleaner to deal with. But is there a way to include output piping when using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution would be to use [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html), a standard part of Ruby which has lots of utilities for opening processes and arranging their pipes.

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
require 'open3'
Open3.pipeline(['ls', '-l'], ['grep', 'z'])
```

When you run this, the standard output pipe of the last command in the pipeline gets connected to the pre-existing standard output pipe of the Ruby process.  This means that you will be able to see any output immediately as it is produced instead of waiting for the processes to end.  Another benefit of this method is that it does not spawn a shell; it just spawns the processes directly.

Another option is to simply use [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join) to join the arguments together with spaces before passing them to `sh`.  You just have to watch out for the possibility that your arguments might have spaces in them, and if so then you have to quote or escape them properly.  This method would spawn a shell to process your command, and it should also provide immediate output for long-running processes.

Comment: Joining everything into a string is definitely something I'd like to avoid. I also don't really need to process the output of these commands: I'd like to reduce the amount of spew to the console, but it should still go to the console. All my script wants or needs is the success/failure exit code.

Comment: OK, then `Open3.pipeline` sounds like the right solution for you, as described in my answer.  It seems to return an array of `Process::Status` objects.

Comment: Did a quick proof-of-concept with this approach, and it seems viable. Should be able to abstract the details in a function that presents almost the same API as `sh`. Will give this a try in the "real" script shortly.